# Looking for the name of a novel I read in the last 6 years (2003+ i think)

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

The book follows two fellows who somehow had something to do with an extraordinary tech advance, kept the patents i guess, and have a lot of clout. Artificial Intelligence has been achieved, but in the the process the AI's far outstripped humanity and then took off to their own area (planet, galaxy, dimension? not sure).

One of the fellows starts to follow some "paths" i want to say "fairy paths" that are on some planets, that lead to other planets, which have their own paths, etc. These may have been designed by the AI's.

Very little else do i remember, but it was excellent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Peter F Hamilton's series which includes [*Misspent Youth*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misspent_Youth), [the Commonwealth Saga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_Saga) and [the Void Trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_Trilogy). From your description, I'd guess it's the Commonwealth Saga, but might be the Void Trilogy.

Comment: oh dear, i hope you are not right. I hated "the reality dysfunction" stuff. But i loved the book i described!

Comment: Damn, I think you ARE right. You are pretty amazing at this. My description was quite vague. Thanks. Still kinda bugs me that it is the same author as the "reality disfunction", but oh well.